# Need help with update for observer c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a order beverage type program. I am tryig to implement observer pattern so when the order is placed the cellphone /observer will display the order, basically letting them know of an update..

I just dont know how to do this. If i pass TheOrder class in update()order classes..i get a slew of errors. too many to post.. update() is in observer and cellphone and in the TheOrder class..

here is my observer classes:

```
#ifndef _OBSERVER_
#define _OBSERVER_

#include <string>
//#include "TheOrder.h"

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {

//class Subject;
class Observer {

protected: virtual ~Observer() = 0 {
};
public: 
//  virtual 
    virtual void update()= 0;
};

} // namespace Observer
} // namespace HeadFirstDesignPatterns

#endif
```

here is the observer concrete class

```
#ifndef _CELLPHONE1_
#define _CELLPHONE1_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {

class CellPhone1: public Observer {
public: 
    std::string _number;


    CellPhone1(std::string number){
        _number = number;
    }

    void update()
 {
     std::cout << "BUZZZZZZZ - CellPhone #" << _number << " your order is ready " << endl;
}
};

} // namespace Observer
} //

#endif
```

here is the subject class

```
#ifndef _SUBJECT_
#define _SUBJECT_

#include "Starbuzz.h"
//#include "Starbuzz2.h"
#include "Observer.h"
#include <list>
#include "Beverage.h"

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {

class Subject {

protected: virtual ~Subject() = 0 {
};
public: virtual void registerObserver( Observer* o ) = 0;
public: virtual void removeObserver( Observer* o ) = 0;
public: virtual void notifyObservers() = 0;
};

} // namespace Observer
} 

#endif
```

here is the subjects concrete class

```
#ifndef _THE_ORDER_
#define _THE_ORDER_


#include "Beverage.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "Order.h"

#pragma once;
//class Order;
using namespace CoffeeHouse::Decorator;
namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {


class TheOrder : public Subject {



 private: mutable std::list< Observer* > _observers;
private: mutable std::list< Order* > _orders;

//public: virtual ~Order() = 0 
//public: ~TheOrder();
public: void NewOrder(Beverage* bev, Observer* cellphone)
        {
        //  _orders.push_front(new Order(bev, cellphone));
       //_//observers.push_front(new Order(bev));

        }

public: void registerObserver( Observer* o ) { assert( o );
    _observers.push_back(o);
}

public: void removeObserver( Observer* o ) { assert( o );
    _observers.remove(o);
}

public: void notifyObservers()  {
    for( std::list< Observer* >::iterator iterator = _observers.begin(); _observers.end() != iterator; ++iterator ) {
        Observer* observer = *iterator;
        observer->update();

    }
}


};
//}
} // namespace Observer
} // namespace CoffeeHouse

#endif
```

here is the observer concrete class

```
#ifndef _CELLPHONE1_
#define _CELLPHONE1_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {

class CellPhone1: public Observer {
public: 
    std::string _number;


    CellPhone1(std::string number){
        _number = number;
    }

    void update()
 {
     std::cout << "BUZZZZZZZ - CellPhone #" << _number << " your order is ready " << endl;
}
};

} // namespace Observer
} //

#endif
```

main()

```
#include "Starbuzz.h"   //just header files
#include "Starbuzz2.h"  // just header files
#include "Subject.h"

#include "TheOrder.h"
#include "CellPhone2.h"
#include "CellPhone1.h"

using namespace CoffeeHouse::Decorator;
using namespace CoffeeHouse::Observers;


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{

Beverage* beverage2 = new DarkRoast();
beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);
beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);
beverage2 = new Whip(beverage2);

std::cout << "Current Orders: "  << endl;
std::cout << beverage2->getDescription() 
    << " $" 
    << beverage2->cost() 
    << std::endl;

Beverage* beverage3 = new HouseBlend();
beverage3 = new Soy(beverage3);
beverage3 = new Mocha(beverage3);
beverage3 = new Whip(beverage3);
std::cout << beverage3->getDescription() 
    << " $" 
    << beverage3->cost() 
    << std::endl;

delete beverage3;
delete beverage2;
//delete beverage;

Bagel* bagel = new Plain();
std::cout.setf( std::ios::showpoint);
std::cout.precision(3);
std::cout << bagel->getDescription() 
    << " $" 
    << bagel->cost() 
    << std::endl;

Bagel* bagel2 = new Raisen();
bagel2 = new Myhummus(bagel2);
bagel2 = new SesemeSeed(bagel2);
bagel2 = new CreameCheese(bagel2);
std::cout << bagel2->getDescription() 
    << " $" 
    << bagel2->cost() 
    << std::endl;



Bagel* bagel3 = new Onion();
bagel3 = new Myhummus(bagel3);
bagel3 = new SesemeSeed(bagel3);
bagel3 = new CreameCheese(bagel3);
std::cout << bagel3->getDescription() 
    << " $" 
    << bagel3->cost() 
    << std::endl;


TheOrder* orders = new TheOrder();
CellPhone1* cellphone1 = new CellPhone1("1");
orders->registerObserver(cellphone1);
orders->notifyObservers();

TheOrder* order = new TheOrder();
CellPhone1* obj2 = new CellPhone1("3");
order->registerObserver(obj2);
    order->notifyObservers();


return 0;
}
```

i just would like to send the order into cellphone1 class so i can display each different order.. i think i need to send it in through the update function..

because in cellphone1 is the observer so i wold like to display the order there..

In the TheOrder class there is a notifyObservers() function do i need to pass this pointer? also

Comment: Isn't this the same question you just posted?  We didn't want to read **all** of your code then, we still don't.  You need to reduce the amount of code that you post so the question is clear and concise.  Start by removing all code that has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: icelated - I have ADHD.  Unless you can really sweep me away with an astoundingly interesting problem, and yet another observer implementation is not, then you really need to keep your question short and distinct if you want to enable me to help you.  As it stands it is simply not possible for me to.

Comment: every code i posted is code you need to see. how can i make it less when there are multiple updates in different classes?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it might be worth looking at the signal or signal2 library in boost.

Comment: I think there is a missing "homework" tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to implement the Observer pattern.  In the first, each Observer holds on to a reference to the Observable.  In your case, you would need to tell each Cellphone object which Order objects it's waiting on.  If you only had at most one order per cellphone, this wouldn't be too tricky.  If you could have more than order per cellphone, you would have to manage that somehow in the cellphone class.

The second common way (and what I would do in your case), is to pass the Observable to the Observer in the `update()` method.  In your case, you would change the signature of `update` in `Observer` and all of its subclasses to:

```
void update(TheOrder *order);
```

Then you would have access to the specific completed order in the cellphone's `update` method.

Comment: if i do that i get 2 errors: error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'TheOrder and error C2259: 'CoffeeHouse::Observers::CellPhone1' : cannot instantiate abstract class. now, if i include "TheOrder.h" it gives me more errors - like subject class is not defined now

Comment: Since you're just using a pointer to `TheOrder`, you can forward declare it as `class TheOrder;` instead of including `TheOrder.h`.  Make sure you also changed the signature of `CellPhone1`'s `update` method to the new method signature.  Also, you *must* include Subject.h in TheOrder.h, because `TheOrder` is a subclass of `Subject`.  The only reason it was working before was because of the order of includes in `main.cpp`.  You should never rely on include order for your program to work correctly.

Comment: that worked.. however,i dont want to pass in theorder since there is no order there - i am creating the order in main can i pass that some how from main?

Comment: You will have to pass it through `notifyObservers`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to fix:

```
protected: virtual ~Observer() = 0 { };
```